# Ireport sub-report on List using Beans

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am using a bean object for a datasource. The data source contain several properties-- one of which is a list of line items that I am trying to to use.. By bean looks like like this:

```
String name;
String address;
List<DetailRecord> records;
```

I want to have the records show up as the detail lines int the report. I know I need to setup a sub-report, but I'm not sure how to set the sub-report to use the records element of the current parent data item as the datasource.

Answer (score 6):

Ok..I figured out what I needed to do.  For the sub-report I need to specify the datasource
this way:

```
 new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{records})
```

There are a couple of "Gotcha's" here that had me stuck for a little while:

- You must use the full class name (using just JRBeanCollectionDataSource) will not work
- In the main report you must set the type of the records to java.util.list (or the appropriate class.

My attempts kept bombing (with no visible error) due to the fact that the records field in the parent was defaulted to String. Once I changed it to a list, things started working.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, it may help somebody :).

1. from master report, for sub-report set - use datasorce expression.
2. datasource expression set like - new MySubRepClass($F{list}.get(counter)).
3. MySubRepClass is the class that is a bean data source for the sub-report (set like datasource bean) and list (property in the master report) contains its instances.
4. MySubRepClass should implement JRDataSource

gluck!